Was the purple scene in Guardians of the Galaxy a shout-out to the comics?
There's a well-known scene in the first Guardians of the Galaxy film where the Guardians stand together surrounded by purple light. In-universe, that is justified because purple is the colour of the

 Power Stone, which Quill is holding.

Even so, the scene is so highly coloured it's reminiscent of either a cartoon or a comic strip, where it's common to focus on the action by drawing the character(s) against a simple monochrome background. The shade of purple is also somewhat close to the magenta used as a primary colour in a lot of comic book printing processes - and comic artists over the years have had reasons to be biased towards primary colours.
Was that scene either directly based on a similar scene in a comic, or alluding to one?
I haven't found any reference online to an analogous comic story, but I'm not much of a comic buff so might be looking in the wrong places.

This perfectly could be an example of a question which hasn't an answer because you cannot prove that something that doesn't exists, effectively, doesn't exists

@Bardo True - but it will only lack an answer if the real answer is no, and even then there's the chance that someone involved with the film has answered a similar question.
